# Reporting a bug about reCAPTCHA integration to blogs

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha, blog

Trying to comment on the InfoSec blog today (http://security.blogoverflow.com/2014/06/should-we-rethink-our-entire-password-strategy/), I was redirected to a page stating "To use reCAPTCHA you must get an API key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin" (in wp-comments-post.php).

I'm unsure whether this bug is specific to the blogs or to the InfoSec subsite or even the InfoSec blog.

Comment: Whoops! In fairness, the fix for the other bug didn't work for me so the two issues were not *entirely* duplicate :-)

Comment: More likely the fix was deployed only for http://blog.stackoverflow.com/ and not http://blogoverflow.com - still, same root cause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be fixed now. Please let me know if you're still having any issues.

Comment: The error still occurs, when using my account or publishing an anonymous comment. Is there any other step I can take to help debug?

Comment: Sorry, found another issue on our end. Working on it now.

Comment: OK, should be fixed now, for reals :)

Comment: Time for a diamond? :)

Comment: Confirming it's fixed! I still had a glitch on my first visit after your last message, @alienth. The UI space for the reCAPTCHA spinner said the domain was invalid for the key, and I could comment, but my comment does not appear on the site and any attempt to re-post it resulted in SE telling me I was posting a duplicate comment. Well, too bad! Anyway, I tested again and it now seems to be working.

Comment: @alienth so you're the one we blame for the DDoS now? :P baptism of fire!